# Windows 7 open/save dialog default location

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 and Google Chrome. When i save some file using Google Chrome, and later try to open some other file (upload file to "Google drive" for example) my "Open dialog" will open exactly on location where I saved a file earlier.

Is there a way to set "open" and "save" dialog so it ALWAYS open "My Documents" (or some other location), NOT "last saved file" location?

Answer (score 0):

For open only:

While browsing folders in the Computer folder, you can apply the current view setting to all folders on your computer that are optimized for the same content as the folder you have open. For instance, the My Pictures folder is optimized for picture files. If you open this folder and change the view to Large Icons, you can apply the Large Icons view to every folder that's optimized for pictures. (This setting does not apply when viewing files and folders using libraries.)

1. Open a folder, click the arrow next to the Views button Picture of the Views button on the toolbar, and choose a view setting.
2. On the toolbar, click Organize, and then click Folder and search options.
3. In the Folder Options dialog box, click the View tab, click Apply to Folders, click Yes, and then click OK.

Some have reported that if the it doesn't work to close the dialog while holding CTRL.

As for saving (and opening), you could always add the folder to the left side of the dialog (where the My Documents / Recent boxes are). Not exactly what you wanted but maybe a work around.

Comment: No luck, won't work! :\

Comment: What about the work around - making a menu in the dialogue box a short cut to your most used location. You could take that further - link to a single folder which only contains shortcuts to your saved to folders (if you have multiple folders)

Comment: Opening always, by default, at the same location (not "last saved" location) would better suit me